# How to read a set of text files in to a single list in python

Tags: python

I have a set of text files and i am trying to read it into a single list.but when i execute my code

```
def get_documents():
 path1 = "D:/set/"
 texts=[]
 listing1 = os.listdir(path1)
 for file in listing1:
    with open(path1+file,'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
    texts.append(lines)
 print texts
```

I am getting output as list of lists

```
[['Wanna see Riya Somani :) wish lyf olso moment lyk end half galfrnd... :) '], ['Worst book Mr. Chetan Bhagat.. Plz better stori ']]
```

How can i get it as a single list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe instead of this:

```
texts.append(lines)
```

Do this:

```
texts.extend(lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `+=` to achieve that.

```
texts += lines
```

Answer (score 0):

as you might have guessed, splitlines() returns a list, so when you put the result into another list (in your case, texts), you will have a list containing some lists. so a way to reach your desired result is to use:

```
new_list = [item for sub_list in texts for item in sub_list]
```

new_list would be your desired list